# How can I implement dart binary search algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, flutter, dart

How can I use this binary search algorithm in the dart main function?

```
int binarySearch<T>(List<T> sortedList, T value,{int Function(T, T)? compare}) {
 compare ??= defaultCompare(); // I do not understand this line code
 var min = 0;
 var max = sortedList.length;
 while (min < max) {
   var mid = min + ((max - min) >> 1);
   var element = sortedList[mid];
   var comp = compare(element, value); // I do not understand this line code 
   if (comp == 0) return mid;
   if (comp < 0) {
     min = mid + 1;
   } else {
     max = mid;
   }
 }
 return -1;
}
```

Why use this line of code?

```
{int Function(T, T)? compare} 
compare ??= defaultCompare(); 
var comp = compare(element, value);
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'd expect `} else {  max = mid;` --> `} else {  max = mid - 1;`.

Comment: Rashidul, Minor: Why use `(max - min) >> 1` instead of `(max - min) / 2`? Certainly your compiler can use either well.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/binarySearch.html  flutter official documentation uses this way. I can't understand  way

Comment: Which type of data you want to search?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Are you trying to *implement* binary search yourself, or are you asking how to use the existing implementation?

Comment: how to use the existing implementation

Answer (score 0):

`??=` is a null aware assignment operator. https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assignment-operators

The code should read `compare ??= defaultCompare;` which means, if the variable `compare` is `null`, "tear off" the function `defaultCompare` and assign it to the variable `compare`.

In dart a function is an object, and can be stored in a variable. https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions-as-first-class-objects

`var comp = compare(element, value);` is calling the function held in the variable `compare` and assigning the result to the new variable `comp`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a builtIn function binarySearch() in 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'. You can use this function in the main instead of writing the same from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

```
int? binarySearch(List list, int item) {
int low = 0;
int high = list.length;
while (low <= high) {
int mid = ((low + high) / 2).floor();
int guess = list[mid];
if (guess == item) {
  return guess;
} else if (guess > item) {
  high = mid - 1;
} else {
  low = mid + 1;
}
}
return null;
}
```